# Password reset programs only find passwords from one OS on a dual-boot system

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, passwords, multi-boot

I have an Acer laptop with Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

I need to reset the passwords on Windows Vista, but the password reset programs I have tried only find the Windows 7 passwords and not the Windows Vista passwords.

Does anyone know how to find the Vista passwords? The computer starts up in Vista.

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: I have tried OffLine NT and OPHCRACK.  Both find Pwds for the win 7 but not the Vista OS.

Answer (score 8):

## Simple way, see: https://superuser.com/questions/694295/password-reset-disk/694455?noredirect=1#comment883040_694455

Evaluate [Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack 2011 R2 (x86 and x64) - (English)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?PV=42:178#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=178&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0)

Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset

DaRT 5.0 - Windows XP;    DaRT 6.5 - Vista; DaRT 7.0 - Windows 7;

Locksmith - reset password tool

## x86 - only x86 system!

## x64 - only x64 system!

## DaRT language = System Language

## Need system instalation CD!

Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack 2011 R2

[image: Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack 2011 R2]

Select Windows 7 x64 Diagnostic and Recovery

[image: Create Windows 7 x64 Diagnostic and Recovery bootable ISO]

Run Windows 7 x64 Diagnostic and Recovery setup

[image: Run Windows 7 x64 Diagnostic and Recovery setup]

Open Windows 7 x64 Recovery image wizard

[image: Open Windows 7 x64 Recovery image wizard]

Run Windows 7 x64 Recovery image wizard

[image: Run Windows 7 x64 Recovery image wizard]

## Select Windows 7 x64 installation CD

[image: Select Windows 7 x64 installation CD]

Disable Crash Analyzer

If need Crash Analyzer previously install Windows Driver Kit Version, Debugging Tools for Windows and Windows Symbol Packages.

See: [Download and Install Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)

[MDOP – DaRT Crash Analysis Tools](http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2011/02/mdop-dart-crash-analysis-tools.html)

Additional:

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34794)

[Download & Package MSDN & TechNet Content](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/626677ab-c35f-4f3d-9f7c-6b471b1195dd)

[Windows Hardware Certification Kit Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852366)

[Driver Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454508.aspx)

Stop BSOD IRQL_LESS_OR_EQUAL

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\MemoryManagement
DisablePagingExecutive DWORD 1
```

[image: Disable Crash Analyzer]

Set DaRT ISO name

[image: Set DaRT ISO name]

Create DaRT boot image

[image: Create DaRT boot image]

Burn DaRT dialog

[image: Burn DaRT dialog]

## Boot from DaRT boot image

[image: Boot from DaRT boot image]

Network init

[image: Network init]

select locale

[image: select locale]

wait search Windows system

[image: wait search Windows system]

select Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset

[image: select Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset]

select Locksmith tool

[image: select Locksmith tool]

Locksmith wizard dialog

[image: Locksmith wizard dialog]

select user

[image: select user]

Reset user password

[image: Locksmith reset user password]

Finish Locksmith wizard, or reset other users passwords and restart.

[image: Finish Locksmith wizard, or reset other users passwords and restart.]

## Boot Windows 7 x64

Set new password message

[image: Set new password message]

Set new password dialog

[image: Set new password dialog]

apply new password

[image: apply new password]

change password information message

[image: change password information message]

The end!

[image: The end)]

Comment: @user199294 See new step-by-step manyal. Good Luck!

Comment: Why do you recommend disabling the Crash Analyzer before creating the DaRT ISO? Any particular reason for this?

Comment: @Karan Choose the appropriate version of the operating system Windows Driver Kit Version, Debugging Tools for Windows and Windows Symbol Packages and then put the Crash Analyzer. Still need some interpret dumps opreatsionnoy system. Just a little bit, this problem goes beyond the question of the password change. Ok, I add this info.

Comment: @Karan Add MSDN Library official free download location. May too modify kernel KeBugCheckEx and block BSOD ...