# Windows XP blue screen of death even in Safe mode

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, bsod

So I was using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) option to save HDD space, and when it "finished", my computer just went off. And now whenever I try to start it it shuts down with the [Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windows-xp) [blue screen of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), even in Safe mode.

What's the safest approach to fix this while preserving the data in the hard drive? I know it's too much to ask, but I had some important stuff there.

Comment: Need a mini dump file.

Comment: @STTR but how do I use that if I can't access the computer?

Comment: Your need DaRT http://superuser.com/questions/552189/password-reset-programs-only-find-passwords-from-one-os-on-a-dual-boot-system/552201#552201
 or WinPE or Window7/8/Vista/2008/2008R2 boot CD or liveCD ... boot in CD, copy mini dump file. But your need setup mini dump mount and change registry. Found boot or recovery CD plz, from first step.

Comment: What is the stop code reported on the BSoD?

Answer (score 0):

You cat try a repair using XP CD, search on google the steps (press R to try a repair)
or if your OS is destroyed try to install a new OS but without formatting the HDD. All your programs will be useless but the data (all file types) will be untouched