# HP MediaSmartServer EX475 running WHS has unknown password

Tags: windows-home-server

Out of the box (yes, an old one) the MSS has an inbuilt password that doesn't seem to to get reset by either system restore or factory reset. Any ideas on hwo to override/change the password?

Comment: What kind of password is it?  Like, is it a Windows password, or some kind of hardware password?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/552189/password-reset-programs-only-find-passwords-from-one-os-on-a-dual-boot-system/552201#552201

Comment: @Frank - There is no version of Windows that has a user account with a password already selected.