# Is there a way to cancel sfc /scannow in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, sfc

After launching the `sfc /scannow` resource checker from a command prompt or a batch file, is there any way to cancel the process or does the process have to be left to complete?

In Windows XP, `sfc /cancel` would allow this.  However it does not appear to be the case in Windows 7.

I have tried `tasklist` hoping to find the image name and then use `taskkill` to kill it, but I cannot identify the `sfc /scannow` process from the list.

Can anyone tell me which is the correct process to kill?  Or is there another way to cancel the `sfc /scannow`?

EDIT:

To be clear: Ctrl+C only ends the command prompt readout but NOT the process.  This can be seen as trying to run another `sfc /scannow` after Ctrl+C gets the response `Another servicing or repair operation is currently running`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a bad idea. Also I think your method of verifying it has stopped might be wrong.

On my computer I ran `sfc /scannow`. Once it had started I opened another cmd prompt and ran `taskkill /IM sfc.exe /T /F`. This killed the sfce process and it's child process. I verified this by watching the performance tab of task manager (I am on Windows 10) and seeing that disk activity dropped back down to 0.

I tried running `sfc /scannow' again and it said another operation is running but I suspect that is because sfc marked somewhere that it was starting and never got to unmark that because I terminated it forcefully. Hopefully that will resolve after a reboot.

In summary `taskkill /IM sfc.exe /T /F` will kill running processes named sfc.exe (/IM sfc.exe), kill child processes spawned by that sfc.exe (/T) and do so forcefully (/f).

Comment: "because sfc marked somewhere "  found this solution "dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions"....http://superuser.com/a/608543/40928

Comment: @Moab Nice, but DISM.exe will not access image:C:\ while windows is running.  Potentially we could use the `dism.exe /online` command instead, but `/cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` gets "error 50 - this operation is only supported against an offline image" and does not cancel the sfc mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "another servicing or repair operation is currently running" message

2 solutions :

- Reboot
- Restart TrustedInstaller service :

  ```
  Get-Service TrustedInstaller | Restart-Service
  ```