# Error 80070008 while trying to install Windows 7 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, memory, windows-update, service-pack

I just now discovered that, for the past month, Windows 7 has been unable to install SP1 due to error 80070008 which indicates my PC with 4 GB RAM has run out of memory.  I've used the Windows Update troubleshooter and also downloaded the troubleshooter from the Microsoft Fix it guy.  I've even tried downloading SP1 from Microsoft's website and run it directly.  No matter what I do, I cannot get it installed.

Microsoft suggests that, failing everything else, I should disable my firewall and antivirus.  I am NOT doing that.

Does anyone else know what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: copy the complete folder C:\Windows\Logs\CBS to the desktop, zip and upload the folder (skydrive, dropbox) and add a link here-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the offline installer from Microsoft's [website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842).

Once you have that, disconnect your machine from your local network or Internet connection, and then you are perfectly safe to disable your firewall and antivirus.

Once it has installed, you can re-enable your firewall and antivirus before reconnecting to the Internet or your local network.

Comment: I've downloaded that one and it failed all the same, but I will try your suggestion tonight of disconnecting from the internet and disabling my security stuff then.  Still, while 4 GB is not 8 GB or 12 GB, it's also not 2 GB.  I don't know how I am running out of memory, especially with a resource-friendly OS like Windows 7.  BTW, can you tell me which one I am supposed to DL?  I got `windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe` (I'm on 32-bit).

Comment: You may have faulty RAM. The x86 file is the correct one.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin upload the logs. Everything else is speculation.

Comment: Well, I gotta say... good call on disconnecting from the internet and disabling my secuiryt.  It worked!  SP1 installed successfully.  I hope this helps out others with the same problem.

Comment: Always happy to help.