# Domain Admin Can't login at logon screen

Tags: windows-7, login, windows-domain

There is a particular computer on our LAN running Windows 7 Home Premium.  I am a Domain Admin, and that computer is connected to the LAN.

My problem is that when I start the computer and the login screens comes up, there are two accounts to choose from with which to log in.  But I need to log in as domain admin - I can't get it to offer me the option to enter my username.

I can click on one of those user buttons and get a Switch User button, but it never gives me the option to enter a different username.

What am I missing?  What can I do?  I need to log onto that computer to work on it.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to login to a domain account and not to the local computer account? Is the computer previously connected to the domain?

Comment: The user normally logs in with a domain account.  Yes, the computer was previously connected to the domain.  My problem isn't that I can't log in, the problem is that I can't get a login box to log in with.

Comment: That is unusual. Might be the user that have changed the settings for the login. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394947.aspx fore some basic info about this.

Comment: He could have, as he does have admin rights on the computer; but I have domain admin rights.  Can I change it somehow from the domain controller?

Comment: Possibly you could set it through a Group policy GPO and then restart the computer, but I'm not certain, haven't tried just that. :)

Comment: Okay, either the computer got unjoined, or I never joined it (?) - I tried to join the computer to the domain, but got access denied.  And I can't remote desktop to the machine because remote access seems to be disabled.  Bummer!  But I have a local admin account on the machine - how can I get a login box to log in using that?

Comment: Booting in Safe mode (holding F8) should make you being able to log in as a local administrator?

Comment: Ah!  Good idea - I never thought of that.  Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a particular computer on our LAN running Windows 7 Home Premium ... I need to log in as domain admin

Flawed premise: Windows 7 Home Premium cannot be joined to a domain. From [the fine manual](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/connect-your-computer-to-a-domain):

> ## Connect your computer to a domain
>
> #### Applies to these editions of Windows 7
>
> Professional
>
> Ultimate
>
> Enterprise

Although if you didn't know this, you should not have domain admin rights.

Comment: From Chapter 1, Lesson 1 of [Configuring Windows 7](http://www.amazon.com/MCTS-Self-Paced-Training-Exam-70-680): *Windows 7 Home Premium ... You cannot join this edition of Windows 7 to a domain*.

Answer (score 1):

Win7 Home edition doesn´t support domains, so you cannot login as domain admin.
Cheaper but not for domain use - bad OS choice.
Peters

Answer (score 0):

Ah, here's the problem:

[image]

No wonder I couldn't do anything with my domain administrator account.

As for local admin access, I ended up asking the user for their password.

Answer (score -1):

Try disconnecting the ethernet cable, reboot, and then logging in

Comment: No go.  Same problem.  The screen prevents me from logging in as any other user.

Comment: @BGM http://superuser.com/questions/552189/password-reset-programs-only-find-passwords-from-one-os-on-a-dual-boot-system/552201#552201

Comment: Aawwww...  I don't want to reset the user's password.  Isn't there some way to bring up the Switch User button to log in as someone other than the one's showing?